# knockout mapping viewmodels parent child

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am very new to knockout.js, in fact came across this two days ago when I started to realize my UI scripts were getting out of hand.

So, I have several view models, all being populated using the mapping functionality.

I have the models populating OK from the JSON that is being supplied via my MVC controller.

```
function ChangeViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    changeMapping = {
        'CORs': {
            create: function (options) {
                return new CORViewModel(options.data);
            }
        }
    }
    return ko.mapping.fromJS(data, changeMapping, self);
}

function CORViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    corMapping = {
        'copy': ['VendorID', 'VendorName', 'ContractID'],
        'include': ['CorNo', 'CorName', 'Items'],
        'Items': {
            create: function (options) {
                return new CORItemViewModel(options.data);
            }
        }
    }

    self.CorNoName = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        if (self.CorVersion() > 1) return self.CorNo() + ":" + self.CorVersion();
        return self.CorNo();
    });

    self.GrandTotal = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        $.each(self.Items(), function () { total += this.Total() })
        return total;
    });

    return ko.mapping.fromJS(data, corMapping, self);
}

function CORItemViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    corItemMapping = {
        'copy': ['ChangeItemId', 'VendorCorId', 'VendorName', 'VendorId'],
    }

    return ko.mapping.fromJS(data, corItemMapping, self);
}
```

So that's my view models and this is how I load the vm in the $(document).ready function

```
var vm = new ChangeViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I have all this displayed in a table with inputs etc and all looks great.
But if I change a Total in the CORItemViewModel the GrandTotal in the parent CORViewModel doesn't update. Can anyone tell me what I may be missing?

Comment: Add a fiddle with complete code that would be handy to see whats going on .

Comment: Are you sure that you have to apply binding ChangeViewModel?

Comment: Your computed are added to `self`, but your constructor `return`s the output of mapping.fromJS, which doesn't include `self`. Do you even have access to those computeds?

Comment: Thanks Roy, sorry about that, copy/paste/edit error, added the self to the constructor again

Comment: Oiyl, ChangeViewModel actually has other bindings to it, which are working OK, I just removed them to simplify

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle thx to super cools suggestion, and it worked fine...

https://jsfiddle.net/afvh6d6t/14/

```
code..
```

So I went back to the original, it turned out to be an issue with a bindingHandler I used ko-money that broke the updating, so I used this bindingHandler..

http://djsharepoint.com/post/2015/01/28/useful-knockout-js-binding-handlers

which sorted the issue.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to post.